# Setting Line Styles for gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I am using the epslatex terminal, and I am trying to define specific line styles for my upcoming paper. I created the following styles:

```
set style line 1 lc rgb '#0060ad' pt 1 lt 1 lw 2 # blue 
set style line 2 lc rgb '#dd181f' pt 2 lt 2 lw 2 # red  
set style line 3 lc rgb '#ff9933' pt 3 lt 3 lw 2 # orange  
set style line 4 lc rgb '#ffcc33' pt 4 lt 4 lw 2 # light orange  
set style line 5 lc rgb '#336600' pt 5 lt 5 lw 2 # green 
set style line 6 lc rgb '#9900CC' pt 6 lt 6 lw 2 # purple 
set style line 7 lc rgb '#000000' pt 7 lt 7 lw 2 # black
```

However, the moment that I use the following styles in a different Figure, their appearance changes. What can I do to keep my plots' line style standard without changing when using the same terminal? I use lines with points style. Also, I can not change the thickness of the lines in the styles I use.

Answer (score 0):

The standard gnuplot styles are stored somewhere (certainly somewhere in the gnuplot directory) and I am sure you can modify them such that after starting up of gnuplot you will have these as standard styles after gnuplot startup. (check `help linestyles vs linetypes`).

Anyway, the following is simple and flexible. Simply write your desired styles into a text file and load it during your scripts (check `help load`).

**Style file:** `SO72347937_Styles.gp`

```
set style line 1 lc rgb '#0060ad' pt 1 lt 1 lw 2 # blue 
set style line 2 lc rgb '#dd181f' pt 2 lt 2 lw 2 # red  
set style line 3 lc rgb '#ff9933' pt 3 lt 3 lw 2 # orange  
set style line 4 lc rgb '#ffcc33' pt 4 lt 4 lw 2 # light orange  
set style line 5 lc rgb '#336600' pt 5 lt 5 lw 2 # green 
set style line 6 lc rgb '#9900CC' pt 6 lt 6 lw 2 # purple 
set style line 7 lc rgb '#000000' pt 7 lt 7 lw 2 # black
```

**Script:**

```
### load custom style file
reset session

load "SO72347937_Styles.gp"

set key top left
set samples 20

plot for [i=1:7] '+' u 1:($1*i) w lp ls i ti sprintf("Style %d",i)
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the fast response I will try to implement your suggestion, and I will let you know.